# Handling large amounts of data in Angular

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs

I'm going to build a SPA with Angular. The app will be composed of three tabs. Every tab will hold large amounts of data (basically 100-200 rows and various text fields, drop downs etc).

I'm facing objections from my colleagues to build this as a real SPA - they would like to separate this into three completely independent angular applications, living in the same asp.net MVC website.

My question is: Will holding such data on the client side cause browser or rendering issues? Are they right thinking this is dangerous?

Comment: Do you really have to load all that information at the same time? Could you just load a minimum of information and load on demand the rest?

Comment: @Patrick, the idea is that after the data is loaded on demand, it is kept in the app's tabs so the user can switch tabs easily. This means the data will be there and possibly overload the browser (?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd check to see how big a memory hit this is with a real data set and see if it would tax the resources available to most mobile devices.

My first thought would be 100 rows of data, with 100 columns each of 100 byte strings, would mean ~1MB of RAM per tab.  Even my old phone would have enough RAM to handle that.

"Dangerous"?  What can they do to manipulate that data in harmful ways?

Answer (score 0):

~1MB estimate is based on raw data, if the page uses a lot of widgets which scales as data, it can quickly become nightmare unless data is loaded on demand

Comment: OK, 3X for widgets.  Not a nightmare until you have made up data to compare to my made up data.